# Initializing a variable with echo

Tags: shell-script, variable, echo, cut

So, I'm trying to store a part of the name of a file into a variable for other uses. So, if my file was named hello123.txt and I want to store the 123 part. So I try

> num= echo $file |cut -c6-8

But all it does is echo the 123 and not store that value in the variable. How do I make it so that it just initializes the variable and not do anything else?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `echo`, or just use [shell parameter substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ file=123456789
$ num=$(echo "$file" | cut -c6-8); echo $num
678
$ num=${file:5:3}; echo $num     # substring of length 3 starting from 6th char
678
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose your command in `$()` or `` which will execute it and store in the variable the result value.

```
num=$(echo $file |cut -c6-8)
```

Comment: That gives me the error -bash: 123: command not found

Comment: Does num=\`echo $file |cut -c6-8\` or num=$(echo $file |cut -c6-8) give you the error you mentioned???? cause it is working for me `file="hola que tal";num=$(echo $file |cut -c6-8);echo $num` returns `que`

Comment: Oh, nvm I was just doing some wrong syntax it seems to work fine. Thanks.